# how to make a limit to value that can input in symfony form?

Tags: php, symfony

I created code to create input form that i can edit a value in a certain  database column put i want to but a limit to this value for example i have a row i named "credit" and other column I named it  "less than credit" so when i edit my row "less than credit" so the row "less than credit" will only accept input on it if the value less than the credit value if i have 5 coins on the credit row value i can input on the "less than credit" input form if the value 5 coins or less than 5 coins so how I do that 
my full code

```
<?php

namespace site\blogBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use site\blogBundle\Form\TaskType;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
      //$task = new User();
      $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

      $investor = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id' => $user->getId()));
      $less_than_credit = $investor->getlessthancredit();
      $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $investor);

      $form->handleRequest($request);

      if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
           if(!empty($form->get('less_than_credit')->getData())){
               $investor->setlessthancredit($form->get('less_than_credit')->getData());
           }
           else{
               $investor->setlessthancredit($less_than_credit);
           }

           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $em->persist($investor);
           $em->flush();

           $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();


           /**
            * @Route("/siteblog_homepage/")
            */
          return $this->redirectToRoute('siteblog_homepage');
         }

      return $this->render('siteblogBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
          'form' => $form->createView(),
      ));       

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [expression language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html):

```
/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.credit >= value",
 *     message="lessthancredit should be less or equal to credit"
 * )
 */
private $lessthancredit;
```

Comment: i write this code or code like that on the entity file ?

Comment: Actually this might be a better/cleaner solution !

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like the Callback validator available in Symfony. You can view it on ; http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Lets assume your entity

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

Class User
{
    ...

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validateLessThanCredit(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
    {
       if(null !== $this->lessThanCredit && $this->lessThanCredit >= $this->credit) {
           $context
              ->buildViolation('Less than credit is not less than credit')
              ->atPath('lessThanCredit')
              ->addViolation();
       }
    }
}
```

I think you can do something like this

Comment: Thats correct ! You might need to put the 'data_class' => User::class in the form type, but the validation is triggered by the "$form->isValid()" after you created the form with the $investor.