# How to put the limit on number (1-10) in input field in form component of symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I wrote some code for the form, using symfony form component, but I need to make a limit for number in level input field from 1-10. So, if it is lower or higher it must throw an error or alert. Is there any methods that help achieve that?

```
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($skill)
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array('attr' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('level', NumberType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Create',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary mt-3')
        ))
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $skill = $form->getData();
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $person = $entityManager->getRepository(Person::class)->find($person_id);
        $person->addSkill($skill);
        $entityManager->persist($skill);
        $entityManager->persist($person);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('skill_list');
    }
    return $this->render('main/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
```

Comment: try this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741478/how-to-make-a-limit-to-value-that-can-input-in-symfony-form

Comment: yes, that didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the number being entered into an enity, you can use a fairly standard assertion on the entity itself.  [Range](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Range.html#basic-usage).

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Skill
{
    // .. other fields

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\Range(
     *      min = 1,
     *      max = 10,
     *      minMessage = "You must rate at least {{ limit }} points",
     *      maxMessage = "You cannot rate yourself higher than {{ limit }} points"
     * )
     */
    protected $level;
}
```

The form's `isValid()` will use these annotations to check the valid range of the $level, and return an error to show it the number given is not from 1 to 10.